# Traffic monitoring and shaping (C\C++)

Tags: c++, monitor, traffic, trafficshaping

I want to write a library (C\C++) which would be able to monitor network traffic (TCP and UDP) as well as limit bandwidth to a particular network area (apply different traffic shaping rules to different network zones). This library should work on Windows 7 (64-bit). I would be glad if this kind of library can be written as entirely user-mode. Right now I'm learning about Windows Filtering Platform. It seems like what I need, but there's lack of samples on the net and I've never written drivers before. I will really appreciate if someone will just nudge me in the right direction or give me an overview of how such kind of library can be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Did you take a look at the [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library? It's essentially the Windows version of the libpcap library widely used in the Unix world. The source of the same is [available](http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_1.zip) here. That'll help you get started.

I am not sure about what you mean by limiting bandwidth to a particular network area, though.

Comment: On taking a quick look at the WinPcap docs, it allows you to implement filtering. You should be able to put packets for a particular protocol in a queue after the bandwidth limits are exceeded and push them to the ethernet interface as bandwidth becomes available.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try WinPcap.
"I am not sure about what you mean by limiting bandwidth to a particular network area, though"
In other words: apply different traffic shaping rules to different network zones.

Comment: Turned out WinPcap works great for network monitoring but it can't do traffic shaping: "WinPcap receives and sends the packets independently from the host protocols, like TCP-IP. This means that it isn't able to block, filter or manipulate the traffic generated by other programs on the same machine: it simply "sniffs" the packets that transit on the wire. Therefore, it does not provide the appropriate support for applications like traffic shapers, QoS schedulers and personal firewalls."

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought it does. I don't quite know if there's an open-source firewall for Windows, otherwise that would have been a good place to look at for your traffic-shaping requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in conjunction to using the WinPCap library, you can have a peek at [PeerGuardian](http://phoenixlabs.org/) which includes a driver for filtering out peer IP addresses.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.